# swift if condition with multiple cases

Tags: swift

In c# or others we can use this in IF

ex.

```
if((a=1 && b=2)
   (c=2 && d=3)
){}
```

using ( inside ( to check bool in that statement.

But in swift

I'm trying to make something like this.

```
func IsWorkDay() -> Bool {
   if (monWorkYN == "Y" , weekday == 2)
      || (tueWorkYN == "Y" , weekday == 3)
      || (wedWorkYN == "Y" , weekday == 4)
   {
      return true
   }
}
```

But the ( ) doesn't work here. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: () works but what does the , mean?

Comment: Isn't && = , in swift?

Comment: No it’s && in this case.

Comment: thnx! didn't know...work perfectly

Comment: You error is because that you are creating a method with a bool value returned. However you only return "true" in your IF condition, the rest of scenarios do not have a return value with.   Compiler does not get expected output from you method. that is why xcode throws you a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have to use the `&&` operator, with a comma the compiler treats the expression in parentheses as a tuple.

And please name functions (and variables) with starting lowercase letter

```
func isWorkDay() -> Bool {
   if (monWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 2)
      || (tueWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 3)
      || (wedWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 4)
   {
      return true
   }
    return false
}
```

or simpler

```
func isWorkDay() -> Bool {
   return (monWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 2)
      || (tueWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 3)
      || (wedWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property instead of your function

```swift
var isWorkDay: Bool {
    return (monWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 2)
      || (tueWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 3)
      || (wedWorkYN == "Y" && weekday == 4)
}
```

**Resource**

You can check this for learn more

[Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html)